# Jquery Colorbox linking?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, colorbox

Does anybody know if there is a way to embed a link inside of a Colorbox?  So, for example, I have clicked an image and opened up a Colorbox popup, then place a link in the caption to another page?  Or just navigating to a different page by clicking on the image?

I'm sure there is a way, but i am a little new with Javascript/JQuery.

It's not pretty yet, because it's not done.  But you can see what I'm talking about here:
http://www.catanesedesign.com/test/artists.html. Just click on one of the images to make the Colorbox come up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add the link inside the title attribute:

```
<a href="myimage.jpg" rel="examples" title="Sandra - <a href='sandra.htm'>Go to her page</a>">Sandra</a>
```

Note the single quotes inside the title attribute, or you could use escaped quotes.